# Handling Queries for Multiple Tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am working on a project that utilizes a database with several relations. We are working with tables such as:

- Customers(**id**, f_name, l_name)
- CreditCards(**cardNum**, expDate, securityCode)
- BillingInfo(**id**, f_name, l_name, address, city, zip)
- etc...

Using Java Database Connectivity, my question is, **is there a common way one performs queries on these relations?**

Even before getting to the "guts" of this project, I envision being able to call some method `void insert(int id, String f_name, String l_name)`, a member method of a hypothetical `CustomerQueryHandler` class. This class would of course be accompanied by other methods such as a `delete` and `update` method.

I figured I'd start with an abstract class called `QueryHandler`:

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public abstract class QueryHandler {

        protected String jdbcUrl = null;
        protected String userid = null;
        protected String password = null; 
        protected Connection conn;

        QueryHandler(String url_in, String id_in, String pass_in) {
            this.jdbcUrl = url_in;
            this.userid = id_in;
            this.password = pass_in;

            try {
                this.ds = new OracleDataSource();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ds.setURL(this.jdbcUrl);

            try {
                conn = ds.getConnection(userid, password);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public abstract void insert(/*not sure of signature*/);
        public abstract void update(/*not sure of signature*/);
        public abstract void delete(/*not sure of signature*/);

        /* OTHER METHODS BELOW */
    }
```

There would be a derived class for each table and each derived class would implement its own version of `insert`, `update`, and `delete`:

```
public class CustomersQueryHandler extends QueryHandler {

    public CustomersQueryHandler(String url_in, String id_in, String pass_in) {
        super(String url_in, String id_in, String pass_in);
    }

    ...
```

This is actually the point where I became very confused because, **does it make sense for this to be a superclass, even though each subclass will have its own parameter list for the aforementioned methods?**

Comment: you seem to be describing a roll-your-own ORM - have you looked into any existing ones?

Comment: I've been looking. Can't seem to find any.

Comment: i dont do much (any) java but try starting here for some ideas: https://java.net/projects/activeobjects/pages/Home

Comment: You may want to have a look at [jooq](http://www.jooq.org)